# Page Numbering in Table of Contents is wrong

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, thesis

[![My Introduction starts at page 4 but appears in the table of contents starting from page 28 (the last page)[image]

Comment: You are adding the contentsline at the end of the introduction. Open your introduction.tex file and move the `label` `addcontentsline` and `mark` commands inside thath file, after the sectioning command.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please do not show us TeX code as image, we can not copy and test it!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It worked perfectly!